# Jquery Hide Vertical scroll button when no more list items

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I need to hide the next button once all the items have been displayed.

Here is the full example in http://jsfiddle.net/afnguyen/Dpfvq/

and here is the script that I am trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');

            $(document).on("click", ".next", function () {

                $('.prev').css('visibility', 'visible');

                //.onebysix li could be .w6392597 or another height - whatever you want to scroll the height of
                var scrollval = $('.onebysix li').height();
                var currentscrollval = $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop();
                $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop(scrollval + currentscrollval);



                var maxHeight = $('.onebysixmiddle .items').height();
                if (currentscrollval >= maxHeight) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }


            });
            $(document).on("click", ".prev", function () {
                $('.next').css('visibility', 'visible');
                var scrollval = $('.onebysix li').height();
                var currentscrollval = parseInt($('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop());
                $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop(currentscrollval - scrollval);

                if (currentscrollval == 0) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

The hide previous works fine:

```
 if (currentscrollval == 0) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
```

But i m struggling to know what i should put to hide next.  As this is also a responsive design its making it a bit harder.

At the moment when all items have been displayed it won t scroll any further but i need it to hide the button aswel.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your max_height from

`var maxHeight = $('.onebysixmiddle .items').height();`

to

`var maxHeight = $('.onebysixmiddle .items').height() - $('.onebysixmiddle').height();`

like so [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpfvq/2/)

Also change

```
if (currentscrollval == 0) {
    //hide next button
    $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

to

```
if (currentscrollval - scrollval == 0) {
    //hide next button
    $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

and

```
if (currentscrollval >= maxHeight) {
    //hide next button
    $('.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

to

```
if ((currentscrollval + scrollval) >= maxHeight) {
    //hide next button
    $('.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

if you want the arrows to disappear when you get to the last page rather than having to click them again when you are on the last page

Answer (score 0):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Dpfvq/3/)**

Calculation on scrolling to the bottom of the div was not correct

edited code is

```
var val=$(".onebysix li").scrollTop() + $(".onebysix li").innerHeight()
var maxHeight = $('.onebysixmiddle li').height();
                if (val >= maxHeight) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
```

Here is the complete code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');

            $(document).on("click", ".next", function () {

                $('.prev').css('visibility', 'visible');

                //.onebysix li could be .w6392597 or another height - whatever you want to scroll the height of
                var scrollval = $('.onebysix li').height();
                var currentscrollval = $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop();
              $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop(scrollval + currentscrollval);
    var val=$(".onebysix li").scrollTop() + $(".onebysix li").innerHeight()


                var maxHeight = $('.onebysixmiddle li').height();
                if (val >= maxHeight) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }


            });
            $(document).on("click", ".prev", function () {
                $('.next').css('visibility', 'visible');
                var scrollval = $('.onebysix li').height();
                var currentscrollval =$('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop();
               $('.onebysixmiddle').scrollTop(currentscrollval-scrollval);

                if (currentscrollval == 0) {
                    //hide next button
                    $('.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }

            });
        });
```

Hope this helps,Thank you